# Free Windows software for full-screen (including scrolling) screenshots

Tags: windows, screenshot

I need a free tool for image capture on Windows. The caveat -- it must handle "scrolling" in a window to give me a screen capture of the entire window (not just the showing part of the window, but everything else when I scroll down the page too) elegantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I found a freeware solution - https://web.archive.org/web/20131212132323/http://www.ducklink.com/

**EDIT: Original website is dead. Available now on Archive.org Wayback Machine.**

Last active date for original website, August 2020. Works on Windows 10. Mac and command line versions available.

Comment: Not working for me on Windows 7 , 19 July 2011

Answer (score 2):

Give [Screenshot Captor](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/) a try. The UX is not something to write home about, but it's free and does scrolling.

Answer (score -4):

I haven't found anything yet.  I have taken several screenshots and used a panoramic photo program that automatically stitches the images together.